# uploading io.StringIO / io.BytesIO to postgres as Bytea using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, io, psycopg2

I am using Streamlit, where one function is to upload a .csv file. The uploader returns a io.StringIO or io.BytesIO object.

I need to upload this object to my postgres database. There I have a column, holding an array of bytea:

```
    CREATE TABLE files (
     id int4 NOT NULL,
     docs_array bytea[] NOT NULL
    ...
    )
;
```

Usually, I would use the SQL query like

```
UPDATE files SET docs_array = array_append(docs_array, pg_read_binary_file('/Users/XXX//Testdata/test.csv')::bytea) WHERE id = '1';
```

however, since I have a stringIO object, this does not work.
I have tried

```
sql = UPDATE files SET docs_array = array_append(docs_array, %s::bytea) WHERE id = '%s';
cursor.execute(sql, (file, testID,) )
```

and `cursor.execute(sql, (psycopg.Binary(file), testID,) )`
yet I always get one of the following errors

**can't adapt type '_io.BytesIO**

**can't escape _io.BytesIO to binary**

**can't adapt type '_io.StringIO**

**can't escape _io.StringIO to binary**

How can I load the object?

UPDATE:

*thanks Mike Organek for the suggestion!

example file.read() looks like `b'"Datum/Uhrzeit","Durchschnittsverbrauch Strom (kWh/100km)","Durchschnittsverbrauch Verbrenner (l/100km)","Fahrstrecke (km)","Fahrzeit (h)","Durchschnittsgeschwindigkeit (km/h)"\r\n"2015-11-28T11:44:06Z","7,6","8,5","1.792","14:01","128"\r\n"2015-11-28T12:28:45Z","7,7","8,5","1.473","14:21","103"\r\n"2015-12-24T06:04:43Z","5,5","8,3","4.848","48:01","101"\r\n"2015-12-24T12:15:25Z","27,2","8,0","290","3:20","88"\r\n'`

yet if I try to execute

```
cursor.execute(sql, (file.read(), testID,) )
```

only "\x" is loaded to the db. The whole data is lost for whatever reason
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf0lw.png)

Yet, if I define file as b'"Datum/Uhrzeit","Durchschnittsverbrauch Strom (kWh/100km)"..."8,5"\r\n' - everything works. So my only guess is the problem lies somewhere with io object and .read()?

Comment: Did you try `cursor.execute(sql, (file.read(), testID,))`?

Comment: yes. though there is no error, nothing gets uploaded into the database

Comment: Do you do a `commit()` on the connection?

Comment: yeah. sorry for the vague answer. So the file "is" uploaded, yet only "\\x" part. Yet the file.read() looks like this: b'"Datum/Uhrzeit","Durchschnittsverbrauch Strom (kWh/100km)","Durchschnittsverbrauch Verbrenner (l/100km)","Fahrstrecke (km)","Fahrzeit (h)","Durchschnittsgeschwindigkeit (km/h)"\r\n"2015-11-28T11:44:06Z","7,6","8,5","1.792","14:01","128"\r\n"2015-11-28T12:28:45Z","7,7","8,5","1.473","14:21","103"\r\n"2015-12-24T06:04:43Z","5,5","8,3","4.848","48:01","101"\r\n"2015-12-24T12:15:25Z","27,2","8,0","290","3:20","88"\r\n'

Comment: Is the client you query with suppressing display?  Does `select encode(docs_array[1], 'escape') from files where id = <id>;` give you an empty string?

Comment: No, I can see all other files that I uploaded manually. See the picture in the update. To the second: yes, the command results in the empty string. I honestly don't understand why the data gets lost :(

Comment: Do you do a debugging `file.read()` before you run the insert?  If so, that clears out the IO object.

Comment: Wow! Indeed, I had a print statement with file.read() in there. After I deleted it, it worked!!  Still don't quite understand why, but it works. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: The IO object acts like a file.  When you do a `read()` on it, it reads what's in it and then is positioned at the end of the "file".  The next time you call `read()`, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mike Organek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879904/uploading-io-stringio-io-bytesio-to-postgres-as-bytea-using-psycopg2?noredirect=1#comment111197341_62879904) pointed out the solution:

`file.read()`  in `cursor.execute(sql, (file.read(), testID,))` to get the binary data while **not** reading the file previously did the trick.